# Is it possible for githooks to execute in parallel?

Tags: git, githooks

Currently I'm concerned just about pre-receive hook and post-receive hook but it would be nice to have a complete list of hooks for which it is possible to execute in parallel (if there are any).

I'm asking this because it is important to know if you need to take care to write the code so there may run multiple instances without steping on each other toes.

I'm thinking the hooks get executed for actions that manipulate the internal state of the repository, therefore there can be only one "writer" at a time and if there is eg. multiple pushes happening at the same time, they are queued and processed in serial.

But that's just my guess and I'd like to see some authoritative answer. I don't see an answer to this in `man githooks` and don't know where else to look (besides the source).

Answer (score 0):

The pre-receive and update hooks both run while git holds the lock on the repo (necessarily so, as git is messing about with the pack files and has not yet updated the references).  So these are automatically mutually exclusive.  (That is, as long as there are updates.  If there are no updates, nothing happens at all, so the question becomes moot.)

The post-receive and post-update hooks, however, are run after the lock is released.  So those can in fact race with other receive-pack operations.